# How do I edit the actual code of a java .class file?

Tags: java

I have a jar that I want to take out a class file and add a few lines of code to it. I got class editor, but you can't actually change any code, you can change constants and that is all. I have a program that you can read the source code from a .class but you can't change anything on it. Is there a program or eclipse plugin that you can read and EDIT the source code from a .class file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at decompilers. They'll transform the java-bytecode back to source code. One example of such a compiler would be JD: http://jd.benow.ca/

After editing the source code you would have to compile the code again and pack it in the respective `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

What you need for this is a java de-compiler. This will take the bytecode out of your class file and convert it back to its source. From there you will need to recompile the .java files that the de-compiler produces.

Here are some java de-compilers that I have seen:
http://dcompiler.sourceforge.net/

http://jd.benow.ca

Comment: I don't know about every scenario, because I've only tested them just to see if they actually worked. With small projects it produced correct code that had the same functionality. Obviously it can't get you comments back, which are important.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is an old enough version, you can use [jasper](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/jasper/) to disassemble it into bytecode, edit the bytecode and reassemble it using [jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/).  Unfortunately these tools have not been updated in some time.

They do not produce Java code; you'll have to learn Java bytecode.  But it is more reliable than the so-called "decompiler" methods.

Answer (score 0):

As Java .class files are in byte-code format, you cannot modify them the way you would edit a .java source file. Bytecode is a low level language closer to the machine language rather than Java itself.

If you need to modify the source, one option is to use a decompiler, e.g. [JAD (Java Decompiler)](http://varaneckas.com/jad/), to get a source file and then change it and recompile to .class using javac. Make sure you figure out which version of Java language (1.4, 5, 6, 7, 8) has been used for the original jar file.

Comment: Okay, thank you I decompiled it successfully, but now when I try to compile it using javac it doesn't work because it can't find the other .java files that were in the jar. It isn't letting me compile just one class. Do I have to decompile all of the other classes in the jar and then re-compile them? There is a lot of classes so this will take a very long time to do,

Comment: With javac, unfortunately, yes. You should decompile and recompile the entire jar file. Make sure you also put all other dependant jar files on the compiler classpath.